# Prove: If $A \times B$ is open in $X \times Y$ then $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty topological spaces, and assume that $A \times B$ is a nonempty open subset of $X \times Y$.

Prove that $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$.

(Hint: Take intersection with $\{x_0\} \times Y$ and $X \times \{y_0\}$ where $(x_0, y_0) \in A \times B$  and the vertical and horizontal slices are homeorphic to the factors $X$ and $Y$.)

This is where I'm stuck. How do I use the assumption that $A \times B$ is an open subset of $X \times Y$ and use the hint to prove that $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$ and $Y$ respectively?

Comment: Another way to think about it: the map $X\to X\times Y$ given by $x\mapsto (x,y_0)$ is continuous. It follows that $A$ is open in $X$ by taking the inverse image of $A\times B$.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, so i construct the map as defined by Justin, would i need to prove its Homeomorphic at that point to be able to use the property that open sets map to open sets? Or is it given by the construction of the map?

Comment: All you need is continuity (though it is true that the map is an embedding), continuity follows from the universal property of the product topology.

Answer (score 2):

You could use that the projection map $\pi:X \times Y \to X$ is an open map. That means that the image of an open set via that projection is an open set of $X$. In particular, $A$ is an open set of $X$. The same can be done for $B$.

Answer (score 1):

A base for the product topology on $X \times Y$ is given by $\{O_1 \times O_2: O_1 \in \mathcal{T}_X, O_2 \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$.

Let $A \times B$ be open and non-empty. Pick any $(x_0,y_0) \in A \times B$.
Proof that $A$ is open ($B$ is similar):

Pick $p \in A$. Then $(p, y_0) \in A \times B$ and as this set is open, we can find a basic open set $O_1 \times O_2$, with $O_1$ open in $X$ and $O_2$  open in $Y$, such that

$$(p,y_0) \in O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq A \times B$$

So $p \in O_1$ and $O_1 \subseteq A$ (as $p' \in O_1 \implies (p',y_0) \in O_1 \times O_2 \subseteq A \times B \implies p' \in A$) so $p$ is an interior point of $A$. As $p \in A$ was arbitrary, $A$ is open.

$B$ open goes the same way.